# Creating R bindings for a C++ library. How does Rcpp memory management work?

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm struggling to write R bindings for my C++ package.

I have implemented a Tree structured object in C++. For example I might have the following class `Tree` implemented in C++:

```cpp
// tree.h

#ifndef TREE_HPP
#define TREE_HPP

#include <vector>

class Tree;

typedef Tree *TreePtr;

class Tree {
private:
  std::vector<TreePtr> children;
  std::vector<int> data;

public:
  // A regular tree is initialized with some constant interior degree and depth.
  // An identical  copy of data is stored at each node.
  Tree(int interiorDegree, int depth, std::vector<int> data);

  // To destroy a tree we must destroy its children recursively
  // with a custom destructor.
  ~Tree();

  // Delete all nodes and replace data below.
  void replace(int interiorDegree, int depth, std::vector<int> data);
};

#endif
```

With the following implementation:

```cpp
// tree.cpp

#include "tree.h"

Tree::Tree(int interiorDegree, int depth, std::vector<int> data) {
  // Initialize children.
  data = data;
  children = {};
  for (auto i = 0; i < interiorDegree; ++i) {
    if (depth > 1)
      children.push_back(new Tree(interiorDegree, depth - 1, data));
  }
}

Tree::~Tree() {
  // Delete children.
  for (auto child : children) {
    delete child;
  }
}

void Tree::replace(int interiorDegree, int depth, std::vector<int> data) {
  // Delete child pointers.
  for (auto child : children) {
    delete child;
  }
  // Free vector memory.
  std::vector<TreePtr>().swap(children);
  // Replace data.
  data = data;
  // Recreate subtree.
  for (auto i = 0; i < interiorDegree; ++i) {
    children.push_back(new Tree(interiorDegree, depth - 1, data));
  }
}
```

Now I've written an Rcpp module to expose this to R as follows:

```cpp
// r.cpp

#include "tree.h"
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>

class RcppTree {
private:
  Tree *tree;

public:
  RcppTree(int interiorDegree, int depth, Rcpp::IntegerVector data) {
    std::vector<int> vecdata{};
    for (auto i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
      vecdata.push_back(data[i]);
    }
    tree = new Tree(interiorDegree, depth, vecdata);
  }

  ~RcppTree() { delete tree; }

  void replace(int interiorDegree, int depth, Rcpp::IntegerVector data) {
    std::vector<int> vecdata{};
    for (auto i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
      vecdata.push_back(data[i]);
    }
    tree->replace(interiorDegree, depth, vecdata);
  }
};

RCPP_MODULE(RcppTree) {
  class_<RcppTree>("RcppTree")
      .constructor<int, int, Rcpp::IntegerVector>()
      .method("replace", &RcppTree::replace)
}
```

Now, in R I load this via `Rcpp::loadModule(module = "RcppTree", TRUE)`. So I can create the tree just fine, and all my methods work perfectly, producing the correct outputs in R. However, when I create a new tree with large width and interior degree, it consumes a lot of memory. In C++, I can free this memory by using the `Tree::replace` method to delete the interior nodes, and replace it with a smaller tree. However, when I call the R binding for replace, the free'd memory from the old interior nodes is not available for use, and the new nodes which should replace the old ones will actually consume more memory rather than recycling the memory recently free'd.

How can I get Rcpp to recycle this memory? I've found writing R packages in C++ to be a very steep learning curve thus far.

Comment: From a casual glance I do not understand the question _as you are only showing STL code_ whose memory managed is _outside_ of R and should work called from R the same as outside of R.  But you could try `replace(int. int. std::vector<int>)` to force on more copy and disconnect those ints from R.  Otherwise there is no magic: R has `Calloc`, `Free` amd `Realloc` of memory via its `SEXP` objects.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel thanks for responding, my issue is that even though this works fine in native C++, the memory actually free'd during runtime isn't made available again until object termination (I assume). This causes subsequent `replace` calls to occupy more and more memory, even if the internal memory use of the object should be the same.

Comment: Yes, you already said so.  There is only one venue to pursue here.  R object (and those passed in) are, well, R object and those are reference counted.  You will *not* win by messing with R's internal state, but if you _really_ think this drives it you could force deep copies at handover to be explicitly in memory management on your side. Rcpp on the interface, hand over, STL on the inside, 'fixed cost'.  If you don't see that you are still doing something wrong.

Comment: And yes, this is the right way to experiment and you could also (if you're suspicious) not use Rcpp Modules, do it all yourself and just pass single ints in and out in a radical design, assert it does what you want and build on from there.  These questions are not knew and all this has been discussed here and elsewhere so feel free to search a little.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Your input is enlightening! Thanks for helping me out here. I imagine that in my case deep copies or even serialization would be quite expensive here, since we're dealing with O(m^n). I can't help but wonder if there's another way to handle dynamic memory changes, but I suspect it'll simply require rewriting the library to use R native data structures at its core. Is there a way I could write some custom memory manager perhaps?

Comment: "In theory" via ALTREP, in practice I don't think it has been done.  On the other hand, working with native R objects (if you have enough RAM) and zero-copy is pretty straightforward.  As always, "it depends".